# Github - how to search a specific file with some conditions about the corresponding repos?

Tags: git, search, github, repository

For example, I can find all the repos having a file named "`user.module`" through the parameter "`filename:readme.md`" in code searching.

Meanwhile, I want to filter these repos with the condition "star:>1000".

But I notice that I cannot do the search and condition filtering at the same time since Github distinguishes code searching and repo searching.

Does anyone know how to make such a search, i.e., search all the repos with a specific file and some conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround (after reading of [GitHub "searching repositories"](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/)) is to search for a common term in readme files:

[`readme in:readme star:>1000`](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=readme%20in%3Areadme%20star%3A%3E1000&type=Repositories)

That way, you can combine multiple repository search criteria

But you cannot combine a repository query (with qualifier "stars") with a code query (which has the [`filename:` qualifier](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#search-by-filename), but not `stars:`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not what I want. "in:readme" is a built-in qualifier. If I want to search a file named "user.module", the above query does not work. Sorry for the misleading in my question.

Comment: @Leo That is my point, and I have edited the answer to make it clearer: Repo query and Code query don't mix.